# Mark select fields with same value

Tags: jquery, forms

In my form I have multiple select fields.

See here http://jsfiddle.net/ZNShh/

Now I want to mark all select fields that have the same value with the color red. Can somebody help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What if 2 of them have the same value, and another 2 also have the same value, but a different value to the first 2?

Comment: Each value must be unique. So in your example all select fields should be red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try - http://jsfiddle.net/ZNShh/13/